# CalendarExtender Change date with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, calendarextender

I have a CalendarExtender control on my page and sometimes have to change the date to the next occuring Sunday. I'm currently using the OnClientDateSelectionChanged property of the control to call a function that will add some days to the date until its Sunday.

The problem I'm having is that if I select a Tuesday in my calendar, the textbox will display the next Sunday but the selected date in the calendar is still Tuesday.

How do I update the CalendarExtender to have the new date that has one I selected in javascript? The textbox the CalendarExtendar is connected to shows the correct date...

Comment: is there any reason why you chose to use this calendar control instead of the jquery datepicker plug-in?

Comment: I chose to use this calendar control because I'm developing in ASP.Net and we have to limit what we use. We already have the Ajax control toolkit in our project so I have to stick to that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Changing the value of the textbox that is the **TargetControlId** for the **CalendarExtender** affects the *selected date* if the following 2 conditions are met:

1. An **onchange** event is fired on the textbox (either by changing the text manually or by calling an explicit javascript fireEvent() method.
2. The **format** of the date entered in the textbox matches the same format used by the CalendarExtender control.

That being said, the correct way to handle this is to call the `set_selectedDate()` function of the CalendarExtender control. This one call, not only sets the selected on the Calendar, but also on the Targeted textbox at the same time.

Here's the example code:

```
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
        OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateSelectionChanged" 
        TargetControlID="txtDate" PopupButtonID="imgCalendar">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function dateSelectionChanged(sender, args){
    selectedDate = sender.get_selectedDate();
    /* replace this next line with your JS code to get the Sunday date */
    sundayDate = getSundayDateUsingYourAlgorithm(selectedDate); 
    /* this sets the date on both the calendar and textbox */
    sender.set_SelectedDate(sundayDate); 
 }
</script>
```

Comment: well, i tried that and didn't get it to work. I'm gonna try putting the code in the comments... Here's what I have:

function onDateSelected(sender, args)
{
var selectedDate = sender.get_selectedDate();

while(selectedDate.getDay() != 0)
 selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + 1);
//
alert(selectedDate);

sender.setSelectedDate(selectedDate);

alert('finished');
}


I see the alert that shows me the date and its the right date, but I never see the finished box because I get a javascript error before that.

Comment: Here's the error I get:

Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Are you using a specific version of the AjaxToolkit? I've got 1.0.20229.0

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put my code for the calendar extender:     <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Animated="true" TargetControlID="textboxWeekendingDate"
        PopupPosition="bottomLeft" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="onDateSelected" />

Comment: well, just found the mistake, you had in there sender.setSelectedDate and it was sender.set_selectedDate.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work. I can't believe I missed the underscore in the method name :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" Text='<%# Bind("Date", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>'
                                                                                            runat="server" class="form-control input-sm m-bot15" BackColor="#ffccbb"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="true" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy"
                                                                                            TargetControlID="txtDate">
                                                                                        </asp:CalendarExtender>
```