# Calendar control in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box and a calendar in my ASP.NET web application.

When I select any date in calendar, I would like the date/month/year of that date to be displayed in the text box.

Comment: You can use ajax toolkit calendar extendar control, which fits your requirement exactly, you can see a demo and samples of this control at http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/calendar/calendar.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in .aspx file

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged">
    </asp:Calendar>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
</form>
```

in .aspx.cs file

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Always use google before you ask question :** http://www.google.co.in/search?q=asp.net+%2B+calander+control+%2B+textbox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

check the answer below

```
private void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
}
```

or

use `OnClientDateSelectionChanged`. Similar example explained here well 
[CalendarExtender Change date with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825047/calendarextender-change-date-with-javascript)

or

[Calendar Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/calendar/calendar.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already use the onselectionchanged event but not seeing result directly you could use a updatepanel like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
        onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you were just looking for the event then it would look alike this

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Calendar.cal.SelectedDate.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the "SelectionChanged" Event of the calender control and inside the event write this code,

```
txtbox.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

txtbox.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try looking at the Ajax Toolkit CalendarExtender. This gives you a text box that when you click in it opens a calendar and the selected date is automatically added to the text box.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/calendar/calendar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
        onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```